# Creating a feed with acts_as_taggable_on in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, feed, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm trying to create a feed in Rails utilizing `acts_as_taggable_on` and I'm having a bit of trouble.

In my app there are Users who belong to Groups and every User selects several Tags for himself/herself using the acts_as_taggable_on context `:user_tags`. The Users create Posts which also have Tags, but of the context `:post_tags`.

What I'm trying to do is create a feed for the current User comprised of Posts from within his/her Group that have at least one `:post_tag` in common with the current User's `:user_tags`. So for example, if I have a User that chooses "Developer, Designer" as two `:user_tags`, I'd want to return all Posts from within his/her Group that have "Developer" and/or "Designer" as `:post_tags`.

After hours of fiddling around, here's what I tried in `post.rb`, but it gave me an error ("ERROR: column 'tag_id' does not exist LINE 1"), which seems odd given that tag_ids do exist for taggings.

```
# Returns posts with tags also attributed to the given user.
  def self.from_posts_matching_tags_of(user)
    matching_tag_ids = "SELECT tag_id FROM taggings
                        WHERE  taggable_id = :user_id"
    where("tag_id IN (#{matching_tag_ids}) OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: user)
  end
```

Any suggestions for how to properly create such a feed method would be much appreciated. And if there's any other relevant code you want me to share, just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out a solution that has worked thus far in my (admittedly limited) testing. Hope this is helpful to anyone else seeking to do something similar. Of course, if anybody knows a more efficient way to tackle this, I'm always open to improvements.

I added this to `pages_controller.rb` and it seems to do the trick:

```
def index
  if logged_in?
    @feed_items = Post.tagged_with([@current_user.user_tag_list], :on => :post_tags, :any => true)
  end
end
```

And this on `index.html.erb`:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
    <% @feed_items.each do |post| %>
        <%= link_to post.content, post %><br/>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```